# PHP - CodeIgniter - DataMapper - error with save()

Tags: php, codeigniter, save, datamapper

I tried to make a model with DataMapper, but when I used `save()` to insert some new data, it returns an error.

**Error**

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> You must use the "set" method to update an entry.
>
> Filename: C:\wamp\www\website\system\database\DB_active_rec.php
>
> Line Number: 1174

I have an ID in the database with `auto-increment`, and I used the method inscription from a controller.

**Code**

```
<?php

    class Utilisateur_model extends DataMapper {

        var $table = 'utilisateur';

        var $validation = array(

            'login' => array(

                'label' => 'Login',
                'rules' => array('required', 'unique', 'trim')
            ),
            'mdp' => array(

                'label' => 'Mot de passe',
                'rules' => array('required', 'trim')
            ),
            'nom_utilisateur' => array(

                'label' => 'Nom',
                'rules' => array('required', 'trim')
            ),
            'prenom_utilisateur' => array(

                'label' => 'Prenom',
                'rules' => array('required', 'trim')
            ),
            'email' => array(

                'label' => 'Email',
                'rules' => array('required', 'valid_email', 'trim')
            ),
            'adresse' => array(

                'label' => 'Adresse',
                'rules' => array('required', 'trim')
            )
        );


        public static function inscription($donnees) {

            $u = new Utilisateur_model();

            $u->login = $donnees['login'];
            $u->mdp = $donnees['mdp'];
            $u->nom_utilisateur = $donnees['nom'];
            $u->prenom_utilisateur = $donnees['prenom'];
            $u->email = $donnees['email'];
            $u->adresse = $donnees['adresse'];

            if($u->save()) {

                return array(true);
            }
            else {

                return array(false, $u->error->string);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

The line 1174 is in this method :

```
function insert($table = '', $set = NULL)
{
    if ( ! is_null($set))
    {
        $this->set($set);
    }

    if (count($this->ar_set) == 0)
    {
        if ($this->db_debug)
        {
            return $this->display_error('db_must_use_set'); //line 1174
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    if ($table == '')
    {
        if ( ! isset($this->ar_from[0]))
        {
            if ($this->db_debug)
            {
                return $this->display_error('db_must_set_table');
            }
            return FALSE;
        }

        $table = $this->ar_from[0];
    }

    $sql = $this->_insert($this->_protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE), array_keys($this->ar_set), array_values($this->ar_set));

    $this->_reset_write();
    return $this->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us the line of code at `1174`?

Comment: Yes, this line is in the method insert, exactly in this condition :

if (count($this->ar_set) == 0)
{
    if ($this->db_debug)
    {
/*line 1174 */ return $this->display_error('db_must_use_set');
    }
    return FALSE;
}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out why ...
Because the column names in the database was all uppercase and in the model all lowercase...
But now it's work :D